# Most general function that preserves the group action.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $G$ be an invertible linear operator $G\colon V\to V$ (i.e., $G$ is an element of the group $GL(V)$).

Suppose a map $F\colon V\times\cdots\times V\to V$ satisfies

$$F(Gv_1, \dots, Gv_n)=GF(v_1, \dots, v_n)$$

for every such operator $G$. Can we say something about the algebraic properties of $F$? What is the most general form $F$ can have? Can it be non-linear?

What happens when we restrict this to a case where the $G$s are members of a smaller group, such as Galilean or Lorentz transformations?

Comment: I don't know for the general case, but I have something for the Lorentz transformations : if we denote by $\|\cdot\|$ the Minkovski quadratic form in $\mathbb{R}^4$, we can consider $F(v) = v \|v\|^2$. It is not linear at all but it respects your property since by definition the matrices $G$ of the Lorentzian group preserve $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: Actually for the general case I may also have an answer : take $F : \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x,y) = 0$ if $x^2+y^2 \leq 1 $ and $F(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ else. As $GL(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, you can easily check that $F$ satisfies the wanted property. You can also see that $F$ is again not linear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't require anything about $F$, then it is characterized by its value on one element in each orbit in $V^n/GL(V)$, and that value should be fixed by the isotropy subgroup of that element.

For instance if $n=2$ (and $\dim V\geqslant 2$), then $V^2/GL(V)$ consists of:

- $\{(0,0)\}$;
- $A_\lambda = \{ (v,\lambda v)|v\in V\setminus \{0\}\}$ for any $\lambda\in K^\times$;
- $\{(v,0)|v\in V\setminus \{0\}\}$;
- $\{(0,v)|v\in V\setminus \{0\}\}$;
- $\{(v,w)| \text{$v$ and $w$ are linearly independent}\}$.

Let us fix some linearly independent vectors $v,w\in V$. Then $F$ is entirely characterized by the values $F(0,0)$, $F(v,0)$, $F(0,v)$, $F(v,w)$, and $F(v,\lambda v)$ for each $\lambda\in K^\times$, all of which can be chosen independently.

Since the isotropy group of $(0,0)$ is $GL(V)$, we must have $F(0,0)=0$. Let $G_v$ be the subgroup of $GL(V)$ fixing $v$. Then you can check that $F(v,0)$, $F(0,v)$ and the $F(v,\lambda v)$ should be fixed by $G_v$, which means that they should be colinear with $v$. Likewise, $F(v,w)$ should be in the subspace generated by $v$ and $w$.

Of course this means $F$ does not have to be linear at all.